Why Negate when asking/suggesting?
I have heard a lot of people saying that it's much better to negate the modals or whatever when asking or suggesting—suggestions that are in question form. But, I just don't get why. I mean, is it really better to negate such words (modals and the verb)? What difference does it make?

Didn't we visit this place a year ago?
Shouldn't we get moving now?
Wouldn't it be better if we would do this than that?
Why don't we check the new restaurant nearby?


It's the conventional/idiomatic way of making a suggestion, and it might be considered more polite to use "shouldn't". "Didn't we visit this place a year ago?" is a bit different - it's not a suggestion but is expecting the answer "yes we did".

"We visited this place a year ago, didn't we?" The negation implies a request for confirmation of  what the speaker suspects to be true.

You should change 'Negate' to 'negate' in the title.

[grammar correction: Wouldn't it be better if we did this or that? Avoid would/would]

Well, you got an answer now and you are not responding. I wonder why?

Sorry for the late reply, but would you agree with me if I'd say that saying, "We visited this place a year ago, did we?" would also imply a request for confirmation? I mean, wouldn't the receiver also reply the same thing even if it's not negated?

@Lambie... Thank you for the correction, wasn't able to notice that one.

Why do you keep saying negated? First speaker: What do you mean, John? We visited the place a year ago. Second speaker (John): We visited the place a year ago, did we? is either sarcastic or the second speaker is demonstrating a particular attitude towards the topic. It is always a response to something said previously. Please try and read my answer to understand negative interrogative, which is not a regular negative.

Ahh... Thanks a lot @Lambie... I think it's getting clearer now...

No logical completely logical reason, it's just the way it's done.
A question in the positive form is a simple question, and not a suggestion. If you ask "Should we go now?" you are making a genuine inquiry.  You want to know the other person's opinion.
If you say "We should go now." you are making a very direct suggestion. It might be a bit too strong. The other person is not being given any opportunity to give their opinion.
But we can also use questions to make tentative suggestions.  These are polite suggestions that indicate  "I have an opinion, but it is okay if your opinion is different".  In English we can use negative questions for this  "Shouldn't we go now?"  The questioner expects the response "I think we should go" but allows for the response "I think we should not go".
Negative questions expect a certain response, and so are useful for making suggestions.  This is why "Didn't we visit here a year ago?" isn't a suggestion, but it does expect the answer "Yes we did". This seems to be quite a common pattern in other languages too, but not universal. There is no logical reason, but it is a useful way of adding subtlety to your suggestions.

Those examples are are not negation.
Negation is this:

We didn't visit this place last year.

But this one is negative interrogative:

Didn't we visit this place last year? Yes, we did.

Forming negative interrogative constructions

The negative interrogative form is commonly used, especially in spoken
English:    Doesn't Kevin leave today? I believe Kevin is going to
leave today: is that true?    Don't you think Susie seems a little bit
nervous today? I think Susie seems nervous today: do you agree?
Couldn't you come a little earlier? Would you be able to arrive a
little earlier, or not?    Didn't you want a new car? I thought you
wanted a new car. Is that not true?
We form expressions such as 'Isn't it?', 'Won't he?', 'Doesn't she?'
etc. using the negative interrogative construction. Bob will fix this
problem, won't he? [expected answer: Yes, he will] You were sick,
weren't you? [expected answer: Yes, I was]

negative interrogative
We also do this:
Bob won't fix it, will he? [expected answer: No, he won't]
You weren't sick, were you? [expected answer: No, I wasn't]
From the OP's examples (they all work the same way):
Didn't we visit this place a year ago?   [expected answer: Yes, we did]
Shouldn't we get moving now? [expected answer: Yes, we should]
Expected answers there are like the ones above it. Also, the expected answer is not always the one actually received:

Didn't we visit this place a year ago?
No, actually we didn't.

Negative interrogatives are not about negations. They are about expectations regarding the interlocutor's response.

Why aren't you happy? [negative interrogative, I expect you to be happy. That is what it means.]
I don't know. I'm just not happy. [negative]

